# How to separate what is called an onListItemClick when a list item is clicked?

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have a list of items that include a checkbox. There is text on the left side of a list item and a check box on the right side. When I click a list item the checkbox is clicked and it fires the rest of the intent in the onListItemClick method. How do I change my code so that when a check box is checked the onListItemClick does one thing and when the text is clicked, the onListItemClick does something else?

I have a method like this to refresh my list items:

```
public void refreshlist(){
    mymap = null;

    mymap = providerTester.downLoadinfo(value1,value2);
    list_my = new ArrayList<String>(mymap.keySet());    
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ClassName.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list_my);
  //using builtin list_item
    getListView().setChoiceMode(2);

    setListAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

And then I have an onListClickListener setup like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    My_DownLoad my_dl = (My_DownLoad) map_thoughts.get(my_list.get(position));

    Integer id1 = position;
    Log.i("ListOthers", "onListItemClick position: " + id1.toString());

            Long id2 = id;
    Log.i("ListOthers", "onListItemClick position: " + id2.toString());

        //For Some reason id2 and id1 are the same
        //I was thinking about setting up a case statement if something different happens if I click the checkbox and not the text



    //start activity if text is checked
            //change state of checkbox if checkbox is clicked   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a lot of trial and error, I got this to work. I am pretty happy to finally see what I was looking for. Here is what I ended up with:

```
public void refreshlist(){
    mymap = null;

    mymap = providerTester.downLoadinfo(value1,value2);
    list_my = new ArrayList<String>(mymap.keySet());    
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ClassName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list_my);
  //using builtin list_item
   getListView().setChoiceMode(2);

   setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

and the second method

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, final long id){
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

final My_DownLoad my_dl = (My_DownLoad) map_thoughts.get(my_list.get(position));
final Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);

l.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            //add values to intent
            startActivity(i);

            return false;
        }
    });



 }
```

Comment: there is still a problem where I have to click a list item first and then the longclick works correctly will all items in the list.